# Generate the smallest timestamp in RedShift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a good way to generate the minimum possible timestamp in redshift?
This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(0, 'utc')
```

Comment: This works (with '0' though), and there isn't possibly a smaller date, why would you want a smaller date ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I just need a minimal date, not necessarily the smallest possible date.